# how to fill 2 combobox from data base in html5

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i need some help with my code  the code in a web local system for a electronic store

1. i have a stoke table in the phpmyadmin data base
2. -stoke table(**id,name,price,stoketype**)
3. -**stoketype** must have this kind of data (telephone ,computer,accessories,ect....)
4. i have **2 combobox** and 1 **textbox** in html5
5. the first one is to display all the **stoke types** from the stoke
   table (**working perfectly**)
6. the 2nd is to display all the **electronics(name)** from the stoke
   table having the stoketype i choose in the **first combobox**
7. the **textbox** is used to display the **price** of the electronic(**name**)
   that i  choose befor in the **2nd combobox** my gol is to have a result
   like this
8. telephone - iphone 6s - 300$
9. telephone - iphone 7 - 400$
10. computer - hp notebook 15a - 600$

the problem is i dont know to fill the 2nd combobox and the text box depending on the selected value in the first combobox  cause i need t the data be connected and organized any help :(

first combobox

```
<select class="form-control" name="transt" size="1" id="input3" placeholder="stoke type">  

<?php 
                                        
$q = "select distinct stoketype from stoke";

$r = @mysqli_query($db, $q);                     

$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);

if($num > 0) {                                                   

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$stkn= $row['stoketype'] ;

echo"<option value='".$stkn."' >".$stkn."</option>";
}

mysqli_free_result ($r);                           
} ?>
</select>
```

2nd combobox

```
<select class="form-control" id="select1" name="stokn" size="1" value="stok">  
<?php   
$q = "select  * from stoke where stoketype=??? ";

$r = @mysqli_query($db, $q);                     

$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);

if($num > 0) {                                                   



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    

$stkname= $row['name'] ;
$price=$row['price'] ;

echo"<option value='".$stkname."'>".$stkname.'"</option>";
}}  
?>
</select>
```

the text box  code

```
<input type="text" name="stprice" value=<?php  ?> class="form-control" id="input9" placeholder="price"  >
```

well its working now  with this code with no page refresh
i had to make 3 arrays to eat all my data as a new data base

```
<script> 
    
    var arr = [];
    var arr2 = [];
    var arr3 = [];
</script>
<?php 

$q = "select  * from stoke ";

$r = @mysqli_query($db, $q);                     

$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);

if($num > 0) {                                                   



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    
    
    
    ?>  
    
    <script> arr.push("<?php echo$row['name'];?>");</script>
    <script> arr2.push("<?php echo$row['stoketype'];?>");</script>
    <script> arr3.push("<?php echo$row['price'];?>");</script>
<?php
```

then create a function that read the arrays data and process the data i want
in a new option (node)
ofcourse i need to clear the option each time cause its will just duplicate

```
function f3(){
    
    var x1 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
    
    var i;
    
    
var select = document.getElementById("select1");
var length = select.options.length;
for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  select.options[i] = null;
}
    

    
    for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
    if(x1==arr2[i]){
        
var sel = document.getElementById('select1');

var opt = document.createElement('option');



// create text node to add to option element (opt)
opt.appendChild( document.createTextNode(arr[i]) );

// set value property of opt
opt.value = arr[i]; 

// add opt to end of select box (sel)
sel.appendChild(opt); 
        
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to submit the value you have chosen in the combobox, you can't fill the second combobox and the text box just by selecting a value from the first combobox.

Here is the first combobox , I will keep you code as it is but I will add some of my code.

```
    <?php 
                                    
     $q = "select distinct stoketype from stoke";

     $r = @mysqli_query($db, $q);                     

      $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);

      if($num > 0) {                                                   

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $stkn= $row['stoketype'] ;

       `echo"<option value='".$stkn."' >".$stkn."</option>";
       }

       mysqli_free_result ($r);                           
       } ?>
      </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Select value from first combobox" name="submit">

  <?php
    //second comboxbox depending on value of first comboxbox
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["transt"])){
   $transt=$_POST["transt"]
   $q = "select  * from stoke where stoketype='$trasnt' ";

     $r = @mysqli_query($db, $q);                     

      $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
      echo "<select>"
      if($num > 0) {                                                   



      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


      $stkname= $row['name'] ;
       $price=$row['price'] ;

      echo"<option value='".$stkname."'>".$stkname.'"</option>";
      }}  
      echo "</select>";
      }
      ?>
```

What we did here is that we showed values in the second comboxbox after we have submitted the value in the first combobox.
Don't forget to create a form.

```
       <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];"?>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: thank you so much for this help iknow this solution anyway the problem is i dont want refresh the page  i have thinking with another way  doesnt request a refresh for the page  i did not try it yet but what if i fill 2 arrays in javascript with the stoke name and value and both arrays have the seam id   then i will try to add the data from the arrays depending on the id and the value i want   what u think??

Comment: I have never tried something like this before . But i think you should do a XMLHttpRequest to a php file and get a response.

Comment: i did it and  its working just fine  i just make arrays in javascript and fill them with my  data  like making a new data base but with java script arrays  crazy ha  then i  make a function  in java script that read every array value and compare it to the first combo box   if the values match then  i just add  a new option(node) to the2nd combobox LOL